# Get the uiSegmentControl value for edit

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol, selectedvalue

i have a segment control to define the difficulty level for the preparation a recipe. I need to load the value assign at one recipe that I won't to edit it. The follow the code:

```
@IBOutlet var segNewDifficultyLevel: UISegmentedControl!

@IBOutlet var ingredientTableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet var directionTableView: UITableView!

weak var delegate: AddNewRecipeViewControllerDelegate?

// MARK: - Variabili Globali
var editRecipe: RecipeModel!

var difficultyLevel: String!

var ingredients: [IngredientModel] = []
var directions: [DirectionModel] = []
```

This code is in the viewDidLoad:

```
if let editToRecipe = editRecipe {
            title = "Edit Recipe"
            // Load data from Recipe Detail into editRecipe 
            viewImageNewRecipe.image = editToRecipe.imageRecipe
            fieldNewRecipeName.text = editToRecipe.nameRecipe
            fieldNewQuantityFor.text = editToRecipe.quantityRecipe
            fieldNewPrepareTime.text = editToRecipe.preparationTime
            fieldNewCookingTime.text = editToRecipe.cookingTime
            fieldNewBakingTemp.text = editToRecipe.bakingTempRecipe

            /* Load the Difficulty Level selected in the recipe */
            segNewDifficultyLevel.selectedSegmentIndex = ???
```

Anybody can help me please?
Thx a lot!!!

Model Class of Recipe:

```
class RecipeModel: NSObject, NSCoding
{
    var nameRecipe: String
    var quantityRecipe: String
    var recipeTime: String
    var preparationTime: String
    var cookingTime: String
    var bakingTempRecipe: String

    var difficultyLevelRecipe: String

    var imageRecipe: UIImage

    var ingredients: [IngredientModel]
    var directions: [DirectionModel]

    var recipeTimeInt: Int
    {
        var sumRecipeTime: Int = Int(recipeTime)!
        sumRecipeTime = Int(preparationTime)! + Int(cookingTime)!
        return sumRecipeTime
    }

    init(nameRecipe: String, quantityRecipe: String, recipeTime: String, preparationTime: String, cookingTime: String, bakingTempRecipe: String, difficultyLevelRecipe: String, imageRecipe: UIImage, ingredients: [IngredientModel], directions: [DirectionModel]) {
        self.nameRecipe = nameRecipe
        self.quantityRecipe = quantityRecipe
        self.recipeTime = recipeTime
        self.preparationTime = preparationTime
        self.cookingTime = cookingTime
        self.bakingTempRecipe = bakingTempRecipe
        self.difficultyLevelRecipe = difficultyLevelRecipe
        self.imageRecipe = imageRecipe
        self.ingredients = ingredients
        self.directions = directions
    }
```

...
    }

Comment: can you share the model class / struct of Recipe ?

Comment: Add Model Class. Thx for your attention...

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting index as string in you `difficultyLevelRecipe` then you can convert it to `Int` as set for `selectedSegmentIndex` like as below:

```
segNewDifficultyLevel.selectedSegmentIndex = Int(editToRecipe.difficultyLevelRecipe)
```

But, If you getting some other value like as value/name of `difficultyLevelRecipe` then you need to setup it based on value/name available in `segNewDifficultyLevel`. You need to manage it based on condition by comparing name of segment and your `difficultyLevelRecipe`.

I hope you have clear idea and understand what to do.

Comment: Thank you @Sagar, tomorrow i try your suggestion!

Comment: Sorry @Sagar, your solution crash my app ... i’m search another solution...